# 3D heatmap / gradient using three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, heatmap

I have just started an experiment with modelling a building and visualising it in a web browser using WebGL, aided by three.js. What I would like to achieve is a 3D visualisation of a field like temperature or relative humidity. These are 3D entities that have a value at all points in space, but have no boundaries. An efficient way of visualizing these quantities could be a semi-transparent heat map, a see-through cloud with colours that indicate the intensity of the 3D-phenomenon. Is there some way this effect could be achieved?

Thanks!